# Backbone.js, Unable to understand what is "app.wineList.create(this.model)" in the "saveWine" method

Tags: php, backbone.js

I am unable to understand what is "app.wineList.create(this.model)" in the "saveWine" method. How it will work ? I am new to backbone.js, plz help me to understand this. I am aware of this.model.save().

Actually I have removed some code here. Just I have posted the code where my problem was.

Thanks.

```
    // Models
    window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:"../api/wines",
        defaults:{
            "id":null,
            "name":"",
            "grapes":"",
            "country":"USA",
            "region":"California",
            "year":"",
            "description":"",
            "picture":""
        }
    });

    window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:Wine,
        url:"../api/wines"
    });


    // Views


    window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template:_.template($('#tpl-wine-details').html()),

        initialize:function () {
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this); // (event, function, context)
        },

        render:function (eventName) {
            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },

        events:{

            "click .save":"saveWine"

        },


        saveWine:function () {
            this.model.set({
                name:$('#name').val(),
                grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
                country:$('#country').val(),
                region:$('#region').val(),
                year:$('#year').val(),
                description:$('#description').val()
            });
            if (this.model.isNew()) {
                app.wineList.create(this.model);
            } else {
                this.model.save();
            }
            return false;
        }


    });



    // Router
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes:{
            "":"list",
            "wines/:id":"wineDetails"
        },

        initialize:function () {
            $('#header').html(new HeaderView().render().el);
        },

        list:function () {
            this.wineList = new WineCollection();
            this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});
            this.wineList.fetch();
            $('#sidebar').html(this.wineListView.render().el);
        },

        wineDetails:function (id) {
            this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
            if (app.wineView) app.wineView.close();
            this.wineView = new WineView({model:this.wine});
            $('#content').html(this.wineView.render().el);
        }

    });

    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [Backbone documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-create):

> Convenience to create a new instance of a model within a collection.
>   Equivalent to instantiating a model with a hash of attributes, saving
>   the model to the server, and adding the model to the set after being
>   successfully created.

So it adds a model to your winelist collection, and saves it to server.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand this.

Comment: Why it is prefixed with "app" ? Can't we prefix it with "this" i.e. this.wineList.create(this.model) instead of app.wineList.create(this.model)

Comment: `wineList` is a member of `app`, see `AppRouter.list()` method. you can only say `this.wineList` when you are in the `AppRouter` scope, elsewhere you have to say `app.wineList`.